# Make require() variables global?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am very new to node and I would like to know if there is something like automatic dependency-injection. The reason is that I see many packages (for example in Sails.js) have these global variables that can be used anywhere and I want to know how to do that.

Right now I'm passing my DB connection and ORM for every model and I wonder how can I avoid it. Also, for example I want lodash `_` to be global so I won't have to require it in every file I'm using it.

#### Example of what I have now

app.js

```
var sequelize = require('sequelize');
var db = new sequelize('mysql://root:password@localhost/testDb');

var models = require('./models')(db, sequelize); // I don't want to pass them around
```

models/index.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(db, sequelize) {
    return {
        users: require('./schemas/_user')(db, sequelize) // again I'm passing here, I don't want to
    };
};
```

models/schemas/_user.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(db, sequelize) { // And here I finally actually am *using* those variables
    return db.define('users', {
        id: {
            field: 'id',
            type: sequelize.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        email: {
            field: 'email',
            type: sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either set it as a property of the `global` object (`global._ = require('lodash')`), or just define the variable without using `var` (`_ = require('lodash')`).

However, just as in browsers, it's recommended not to pollute the global scope. Moduling exists for a reason!

Comment: Will leaving out `var` in node really make it global?  Or will it push it to the *default* scope, which is within the module (not its exports though)?